# Android scrolling shows double content

Tags: android, vertical-scrolling

if im scrolling in my setting activity, the content shows up twice. It seems in landscape mode there a new layer which is able to scroll and the layer below doesn't move.

How thats happening? I didn't add really much code in this class.

Probably a stupid mistake from me. Sorry - im new on Android.

Thanks for your answers.

```
public class AppPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate the device the fragment is being created by the framework, so you should not create it.

Do it like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - thats it.

I did not recognized theres a different behaviour to an activity in this state.

Comment: see my answer why u are getting two times

Comment: u should also use my answer to avoid any other problems

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

It will keep your fragment state so you wont lose state , as per @Francesc suggestion.

you are adding the fragment not replacing that is why u are seeing fragment twice.

Comment: Thanks for that hint!

Comment: basically when framework recreate it , it once again add to your view, so u see two fragment as they are being added

Comment: please accept mine or francesc answer whoever helped more

Comment: Sadly.

I would appreciate to give it both.

Comment: no issues, you can accept whoever you feel, helped you better

Comment: This is not the right solution. If you replace the fragment, you lose whatever state you had earlier, before rotation. The right way is to check if the bundle is null and create the fragment only if is is. Replacing the fragment regardless of the bundle value is just wrong.

Comment: i said he should also use my suggestion i never said your answer is wrong, he was asking why he see 2 fragment not why his fragment state was lost, so i said him to use both suggestion